# Get a value list of a enum to a json object

Tags: java, json, enums

I want to create a json object with values of "3D Tour", "Videos", "Photos Only", etc. You can find the enum class below. How can I implement that?

```
package com.padgea.listing.application.dto;

public enum General implements Catalogue {

Tour("3D Tour"),
Videos("Videos"),
Photos_Only("Photos Only"),
Price_Reduced("Price Reduced"),
Furnished("Furnished"),
Luxury("Luxury");

private final String value;

General(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

}

I need a output like this
{General : "3D Tour","Videos","Photos Only",etc}

Comment: Could you provide more context? Maybe the keys to these values and do you use any libraries to work with JSON?

Comment: Please don't post images of code but post nicely formatted text. Why? See here: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Please paste the code instead of using screenshots. Clarify if by "JSON with values A, B, C" you mean JSON with one of all of these values. Are these supposed to be *keys* that can then take different values or values themselves? In that case what would the keys be? Otherwise, where would the values come from. Ideally - give an example input and an example output.

Comment: Can you elaborate what that json object should look like? Do you mean an _object_ or an array? If an object, what would be the keys, what the values?

Comment: If this is for a SELECT element in a user interface, you would probably also need the enum names. Furthermore, it's probably better practice to keep the display texts in a localization file instead of in your code. E.g. a frontend.properties file with lines like 'Tour = 3D Tour'. This allows to add language support easily and also allows changing the display texts without touching the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return a list of strings containing all the values.

```
    enum General implements Catalogue {

    Tour("3D Tour"),
    Videos("Videos"),
    Photos_Only("Photos Only"),
    Price_Reduced("Price Reduced"),
    Furnished("Furnished"),
    Luxury("Luxury");

    private final String value;

    General(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    
    public static List<String> valuesList() {
        return Arrays.stream(General.values())
                          .map(General::getValue)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

And a level up you'll do something like

```
myJson.put("General", General.valuesList())
```

An output will be

```
 {
    "General": ["3D Tour","Videos","Photos Only"]
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The valid JSON would look like this

```
{
    "General": ["3D Tour","Videos","Photos Only"]
}
```

If you would use Jackson library for creating your JSON you would need to create a class like this:

```
public class GeneralDTO {
    @JsonProperty("General")
    private String[] general;

    ...
}
```

Then you would need to create your GeneralDTO object.

You can get all your enum values in an array like this

```
String[] generalArray = Arrays.stream(General.values())
    .map(st -> st.getValue())
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Then using the method `writeValueAsString` of `ObjectMapper` class (part of Jackson library) you can get JSON string from your `GeneralDTO` object.

To simplify you can use `Map<String, String[]>` instead of `GeneralDTO`

```
Map<String, String[]> generalObject = new HashMap<>;
generalObject.put("General", generalArray);
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(generalObject);
```